# Rails console not launching [I'm in the directory]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, ubuntu-16.04

Rails C and Rails S not working when in the correct directory.

have tried:

```
$ bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

this returns the following error:

```
bundler: command not found: rails:update:bin
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

I have ran:

```
Bundle Install
```

this still returns the same error

Have changed directories (higher and lower), repeated steps and attempted commends for same result.

I was running rails server, when i stopped the server and tried to restart server, the error appeared, so I'm thinking this has something to do with a physical location change (potentially the bin file), which is consistent as when I try and run a bin/rails command, i'm receiving an error of:

```
bundler: command not found: rails:update:bin
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

I have tried to rake the bin folder as below:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

however I am receiving this error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails:update:bin' (see --tasks)
```

Finally, I have checked the physical location and there is a .bin file, however this folder is empty and it's not in a .gitignore directory.

Ancillary information
Rails version: 5.1.4
ruby version: 2.3.4
Server: heroku
OS. Ubuntu 16.04 (via virtualbox).
I have not upgraded rails, this is a fresh install

**I am at a loss.**

Comment: I have downloaded my working github copy of my bin folder for this app, and placed this over the existing empty bin folder, and this did NOT correct the problem.

Comment: Can you put the command prompt screenshot

Comment: it keep asking you to run `bundle install`  here `Install missing gem executables with `bundle install` and you are running `Bundle install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rails update:bin` or `rake update:bin` These are the right ways that execute a rake task.

Comment: attempted both of these to no effect, rails still just gives me the new app option and nothing else.

Comment: rake update:bin gives me rake aborted, "don't know how to build task"

Comment: @Realitybites You can use `rails -T | grep 'your task name'` to get the right rake command.

Comment: Daniel, on the money,    rails app:update noted conflicts from my git clone (for whatever reason), post up as a answer and i'll mark it was correct.